# Problem with a C# csproj log file

Tags: c#, logging

I wish to write to output file like txt a log of done C# instruction during debuging my csproj. Is there any buildin function in VS2010 or any idea how to do this.

Comment: What instructions? Can you be specific?

Comment: every instruction done by application like console.write(".."); ... so I can check if the order of instructions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `System.Diagnostics.Trace` class. This will write to the Output window (enable the Output window from Debug/Windows/Output).

Comment: How to use it if I want to run my whole windows forms app.

Comment: @user898569 You need to call Write or WriteLine whenever you want to log something. This means explicit calls in the code, like: Trace.WriteLine("Value=" + i.ToString()). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To write info to your output window while debugging just use `Debug`

```
Debug.WriteLine("Message Here");
```

You might also want to look at [TraceListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracelistener.aspx). You can implement a [custom](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/customnettracelisteners.aspx) one if needed. There are also several popular logging frameworks available for .NET, for example [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) and [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Here's a quick sample of writing trace info to a text file

```
using (var myFile = File.Create("TestFile.txt"))
{
    var myTextListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(myFile);
    Trace.Listeners.Add(myTextListener);
    Trace.Write("Test output ");                
}
```